# My eurostat R Program in filter is not working as I wanted it to be

Tags: r

I need to extract unemployment rate from the [eurostat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=eurostat) and I will only need a specific countries and unit. However, the result that I got for the geo was only CZ, DE, and PL, and unit was more than "PC". How can I solve this issue?

This case happen to the others indicators/variables as well.

```
library(eurostat)


unemp <- get_eurostat("lfsa_urgaed", filters = list(geo = c("CZ","DE","GB","SW", "PL"), age = "Y15-74", 
                 sex = "T", unit = "PC", time = 2000:2020 ))
```

I want a list of the countries with specific filtering as I set in my R Environment.

Answer (score 0):

tried replicating your code example, running on eurostat 3.8.2. Some observations:

- for me, the returned dataset had only "PC" as units. Maybe a previous dataset saved in the cache had those other units? I think in 3.8.2 and earlier versions filtered dataset caching was very basic and it was easy to make the mistake of reading a filtered and cached file that was not what you wanted.

  - You can always clear your cache with `clean_eurostat_cache()` or choose to not use cache files at all by setting `get_eurostat()` argument `cache = FALSE`
- There were only observations from "CZ", "DE" and "PL" as you wrote, but this seems to be a user error/documentation error instead of an error in the software. (Although, if you downloaded a filtered dataset and cached it before you have to clear the cache before downloading again; otherwise the cached file is just read again)

  - Eurostat uses the "Interinstitutional Style Guide" in its work, which explains why they use "UK" for the United Kingdom instead of "GB", the official code listed in the 2-letter ISO 3166 codes. (Another anomaly that you may or may not encounter in your work is Greece, for which you must use the code "EL" for Elláda instead of ISO 3166 code "GR")
  - If by "SW" you meant Sweden the correct ISO 3166 code is "SE" (although confusingly it seems that the CIA is using "sw" as a 2-letter country code for Sweden)
  - You might find this Eurostat tutorial helpful: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Tutorial:Country_codes_and_protocol_order#United_Kingdom

Generally speaking, when fetching data from Eurostat you can either download whole datasets and then filter locally OR you can write a query that includes the filters from the get-go*. If you doubt that filtered queries are somehow not working properly, there is often the option to download the whole dataset and see the different types of columns and variables. Of course, it's good to also ask a question like this or open an issue in GitHub so we can fix any potential problems.

(* There have been, and continue to be, slight differences between these two data sources. Unfiltered data is downloaded "in bulk" as compressed TSV files whereas filtered data is queried through Eurostat's Statistics API and is returned in JSON-stat format. Sometimes datasets downloaded in TSV format can have a bit more data available, most often observations going further back in time. The data you browse in the Eurostat Data Browser is the same data that is downloaded "in bulk".)

Finally, I would like to note that at the time of writing this reply, Eurostat is in the process of phasing out their old bulk download facilities. This wouldn't affect your filtered queries from the JSON API as that was already fixed in eurostat version 3.8.2, but it might affect your other queries. We're currently finalising our eurostat 4.0.0 update that fixes these and many more issues, and perhaps also makes dealing with cached data a bit less confusing. Keep an eye out for the new version!